# Trying to retrieve the User ID from discord using Discord OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, discord

I am using the plugin https://github.com/teamreflex/oauth2-discord and I'm able to connect successfully and retrieve the email and username of the connected user.

I require the user id though, and even though the Identity scope is specified, I am unable to get it. Can anyone help me.